# Django: Create model instance within model

Tags: django, django-models

I have another probably quite basic Django question. I am writing a database app for my classes, and I would like to be able to set the current year from within the app. The idea behind this is that I can manually switch to the next academic year when all the marking etc is done. The function to switch the current year is then supposed to do other things as well - put the students in the new default courses etc.

So I created a model called MetaData:

```
class MetaData(models.Model):
    data_id = models.IntegerField(default = 1, unique = True)
    current_year = models.IntegerField(choices=ACADEMIC_YEARS)
```

It would be great if I could access the current_year in other models, for example to set it as default when I want to enter new courses/students. I tried this:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    try:
        meta = MetaData.objects.get(data_id=1)
        current_year = meta.current_year
    except MetaData.DoesNotExist:
        current_year = 2010
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=ACADEMIC_YEARS, default=current_year)
```

Unfortunately, I get the error "No such table: database_metadata" when I run syncdb for the first time - I would guess because syncdb has not created the tables when it tests the code.

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either put the constant inside your code (if you could hard code the logic of computing academic years. Or always remember to change it manually, which sounds OK as you've already hard-coded `ACADEMIC_YEARS`), or in DB as danodonovan suggests. Or model academic years directly w/o storing a constant in `MetaData`

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class AcademicYear(models.Model):
    start = models.DateField() # or simply year
    end = models.DateField()
    is_current = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-is_current', 'start')

    def clean(self): # only allow at most one current year
        if self.is_current and \ 
           self.__class__.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).filter(is_current=True).exists():
             raise ValidationError('Found another `current` academic year.'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'blahblah'

# then in Course
class Course(models.Model):
    academic_year = models.ForeignKey(AcademicYear)
```

Thus in the Admin, you could easily step up `AcademicYear`s and display them as choices of the academic_year field of the `Course`.

If you still would like to use `MetaData`, just change the `current_year` to be a function:

```
def get_current_year():
    try:
        return MetaData.objects.get(data_id=1).current_year
    except MetaData.DoesNotExist:
        return 2010

class Course(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=ACADEMIC_YEARS, default=get_current_year)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need to use the [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) field to link your models.

```
class MetaData(models.Model):
    current_year = models.IntegerField(choices=ACADEMIC_YEARS)

class Course(models.Model):
    year = models.ForeignKey(MetaData, default=this_year)

    def this_year(self):
        return MetaData.objects.get(current_year=datetime.now().year)
```

To set the default year I've added a `this_year` function to the `MetaData` model. The `Course` models year attribute will call this when setting the default year.

Having said that, it would be much simpler if you used a `DateField` for simple dates.

Comment: The ForeignKey would not help - what I would like to use here is basically a constant that needs to be changed once a year.

My plan is to have a function that allows me to click a button in an admin menu that changes the year from 2012 to 2013, puts all the students in the default courses for the new year and so on. And then it would be useful to use current_year as a default if I want to enter a new course.

Comment: Seems `this_year` after `default=`  needs to be a callable such as a classmethod.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Boat_Owner(models.Model):
      username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True,
      verbose_name="Boat Owner Name")
      address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      email = models.EmailField('email address',
      unique=True, db_index=True)
      avatar = models.ImageField('profile picture',     
      upload_to='static/media/images/avatars/',
      null=True, blank=True)
      def set_avatar(self):
          self.has_picture = True
      def __str__(self):
          return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.id,self.name,self.username,self.password,self.address,self.email)
     class Meta:
          verbose_name = "Boat Owner"
          verbose_name_plural = "Boat Owner"
```